# Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in

Tags: php

I need a little help. Because `preg_replace` is deprecated, I have to convert all `my preg_replace` to `preg_replace_callback`...

What I've tried:

Change:

```
$template = preg_replace ( "#\\[aviable=(.+?)\\](.*?)\\[/aviable\\]#ies", "\$this->check_module('\\1', '\\2')", $template );
```

To:

```
$template = preg_replace_callback ( "#\\[aviable=(.+?)\\](.*?)\\[/aviable\\]#isu", 
                return $this->check_module($this['1'], $this['2']);
            $template );
```

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return'
```

Comment: the callback expects anonymous function, but itself it's not one. Yor second param should be `function () { return ...`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) needs to be a function taking one parameter which is an array of matches. You can pass any kind of [callback](http://php.net/manual/ro/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback), including an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

```
$template = preg_replace_callback(
    "#\\[aviable=(.+?)\\](.*?)\\[/aviable\\]#isu",
    function($matches) {
        return $this->check_module($matches[1], $matches[2]);
    },
    $template
);
```

(PHP >= 5.4.0 required in order to use `$this` inside the anonymous function)

Comment: I know you're copypasting but is it wise to use both $template to catch the result and as the third argument?

Comment: @ArlaudPierre, I see nothing wrong with that. Why create a second variable if you don't need one?

Comment: My bad, I was thinking about `preg_match_all` which uses a reference to an array as a third parameter. Still not convinced you should use the same name for the parameter and the return value, considering the return value might be `NULL`.

Comment: @ArlaudPierre: Not unless there's an error. The manual states: `If matches are found, the new subject will be returned, otherwise subject will be returned unchanged.`.

Comment: Hello, when i tried to use it with following cod,e it doesn't work:

` $source = preg_replace('/&#x([a-f0-9]+);/mei', "chr(0x\\1)",  $source); `