# Replace preg_replace With preg_replace_callback Still Failing

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

I'm working on porting SocialEngine to work on PHP7.

On the default install I get the following error:

```
preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead in 
<b>/home/vagrant/code/mysite/project/app/application/libraries/Scaffold/modules/NestedSelectors/NestedSelectors.php</b>
on line <b>300</b>
```

The code for that error looks like so:

```
$xml = preg_replace('/([-_A-Za-z*]+)\s*:\s*([^;}{]+)(?:;)/ie', "'<property name=\"'.trim('$1').'\" value=\"'.trim('$2').'\" />\n'", $xml);
```

I replaced it with `preg_replace_callback` like so:

```
$xml = preg_replace_callback('/([-_A-Za-z*]+)\s*:\s*([^;}{]+)(?:;)/ie', function($matches) {
    return "'<property name=\"'.trim('$matches[1]').'\" value=\"'.trim('$matches[2]').'\" />\n'";
}, $xml);
```

and now I get this error:

```
preg_replace_callback(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead in 
<b>/home/vagrant/code/mysite/project/app/application/libraries/Scaffold/modules/NestedSelectors/NestedSelectors.php</b> 
on line <b>304</b>
```

This seems valid to me, what have I done wrong?

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21334984/5447994)?

Comment: As said in error message: `The /e modifier is no longer supported`, remove this flag and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
    $xml = preg_replace_callback('/([-_A-Za-z*]+)\s*:\s*([^;}{]+)(?:;)/ie', function($matches) {
    return "'<property name=\"'.trim('$matches[1]').'\" value=\"'.trim('$matches[2]').'\" />\n'";
}, $xml);
```

do

```
    $xml = preg_replace_callback('/([-_A-Za-z*]+)\s*:\s*([^;}{]+)(?:;)/i', function($matches) {
    return "'<property name=\"'.trim('$matches[1]').'\" value=\"'.trim('$matches[2]').'\" />\n'";
}, $xml);
```

What i did was to remove the `e` in `../ie`

Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

Now I don't know anything about anything related to this error or what it means, but here's what I found to fix it:

From https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow/issues/1872616
where they're talking about fixing this magic potion:

> I found that there were four places in this file that needed changing.
>   The two already mentioned and then two more times where preg_replace
>   was used. For me they were around lines 186 + 277.
>
> At 186 and 277 I replaced
>
> ```
>     $vars['location'] => array(
>       'type' => preg_replace('/_(.?)/e',"strtoupper('$1')", $vars['settings']['type']),
>     ),
> ```
>
> with
>
> ```
>     $vars['location'] => array(
>       'type' => preg_replace_callback(   // php5.x preg_replace_callback() method
>         '/_(.?)/',
>         function ($m) {
>           return strtoupper($m[1]);
>         },
>         $vars['settings']['type']),
>     ),
> ```

So I took the original code:

```
// Loop through all the addons and call their methods if needed.
foreach ($addons as $addon_id => $addon_info) {
  foreach ($addon_info['accepts'] as $imp_key => $imp_value) {
    if (is_array($imp_value)) {
      $methods[$imp_key][] = preg_replace('/_(.?)/e',"strtoupper('$1')", $addon_id);
    }
    else {
      $methods[$imp_value][] = preg_replace('/_(.?)/e',"strtoupper('$1')", $addon_id);
    }
  }
}
```

And boiled it and the fix down to these elements:

Original:

```
preg_replace('/_(.?)/e',"strtoupper('$1')", $vars),),
```

Fix:

```
preg_replace_callback('/_(.?)/', function ($m) { return strtoupper($m[1]); }, $vars), ),
```

And they combine to become:

```
preg_replace_callback('/_(.?)/', function ($m) { return strtoupper($m[1]); }, $addon_id);
```

Which, in the context of the theme I'm trying to use, becomes:

```
// Loop through all the addons and call their methods if needed.
foreach ($addons as $addon_id => $addon_info) {
  foreach ($addon_info['accepts'] as $imp_key => $imp_value) {
    if (is_array($imp_value)) {
      $methods[$imp_key][] = preg_replace_callback('/_(.?)/', function ($m) { return strtoupper($m[1]); }, $addon_id);
    }
    else {
      $methods[$imp_value][] = preg_replace_callback('/_(.?)/',function ($m) { return strtoupper($m[1]); }, $addon_id);
    }
  }
}
```

I will also say that it was VERY handy that the file location was given in the error, allowing me to fix an otherwise unknowable problem.